# How to label only certain points in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have a dataframe `global` with three columns `Year`, `MTCO2`, and `Scenario`. I have created a scatterplot that looks how I want it to, but am struggling with how to best label only a few points on the plot.

This is my code so far:

```
plot1 <- global %>% 
ggplot(aes(Year, MTCO2, group = Scenario, colour = Scenario)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Year", breaks = c(1990, 2000, 2006, 2020, 2030, 2040, 2050)) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(title = "Global CO2 Emissions Projections with and without Constraints")
plot1a <- plot1 + geom_text(data = subset(global, Year == 2006 | Year == 2030 | Year == 2050 ),
                                     aes(Year, MTCO2, label = MTCO2))
```

And this is what the plot looks like
[image]

My goal is for the text to be black, repelled from the point with a line connecting it to the point, for there to be one label for 2006, one label for 2030 (for the Global_Constraint line only) and one label for 2050 (for the Global_Constraint line only). I'd also like to be able to write more after the point value (i.e. 8261, base year value). The legend is also showing the letter "a" over the points, which I'd like to get rid of as well.

Here is the data:

```
dput(global)
structure(list(Year = c(1990, 2005, 2006, 2010, 2015, 2020, 2025, 
2030, 2035, 2040, 2045, 2050, 1990, 2005, 2006, 2010, 2015, 2020, 
2025, 2030, 2035, 2040, 2045, 2050), MTCO2 = c(6045, 8039, 8261, 
9149, 9646, 10453, 7889, 6937, 5467, 4400, 2589, 2432, 6045, 
8039, 8261, 9149, 9646, 10528, 11488, 12368, 13092, 13708, 14305, 
14754), Scenario = c("Global_Constraint", "Global_Constraint", 
"Global_Constraint", "Global_Constraint", "Global_Constraint", 
"Global_Constraint", "Global_Constraint", "Global_Constraint", 
"Global_Constraint", "Global_Constraint", "Global_Constraint", 
"Global_Constraint", "Global_Reference", "Global_Reference", 
"Global_Reference", "Global_Reference", "Global_Reference", "Global_Reference", 
"Global_Reference", "Global_Reference", "Global_Reference", "Global_Reference", 
"Global_Reference", "Global_Reference")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -24L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Year = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), MTCO2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Scenario = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: You can use `annotate()` to put the label on your plot wherever you want, and `guides()` to suppress or over-ride the unwanted legends.

Answer (score 2):

I guess there are several ways to fix it. With minimum change of your code, I have tried this:

```
library(ggplot2)
plot1 <- global %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Year, MTCO2, group = Scenario, colour = Scenario)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Year", breaks = c(1990, 2000, 2006, 2020, 2030, 2040, 2050)) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(title = "Global CO2 Emissions Projections with and without Constraints")
plot1a <- plot1 + geom_text(data = subset(global, Year == 2006 | Year == 2030 | Year == 2050 ),
                            aes(Year, MTCO2, label = MTCO2), 
                            color = "black", nudge_x = -6)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the easy way to do this is create the label and then design the plot:

```
#Format data
global %>% mutate(label=ifelse(Year %in% c(2006,2030,2050),MTCO2,NA)) -> global
#Plot
ggplot(global,aes(x=Year, y=MTCO2,label=label)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1,aes(color = Scenario)) +
  geom_point(size = 2,aes(color = Scenario)) +
  geom_text(vjust=-1)+
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Year", breaks = c(1990, 2000, 2006, 2020, 2030, 2040, 2050)) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(title = "Global CO2 Emissions Projections with and without Constraints")
```

[image]